# Display AngularJS TreeView collapsed

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui

I am using angular tree-view. I am referring below url.

http://ngmodules.org/modules/angular.treeview

It is displaying as expanded. but i want to display as collapsed. when the node is clicked then only it should expand.

Please refer.

Answer (score 3):

You have to add `collapsed:true` in each node like following example

```
 $scope.roleList = [
    { label : "User", id : "role1", children : [
      { label : "subUser1", id : "role11", children : [] },
      { label : "subUser2", id : "role12", children : [
        { label : "subUser2-1", id : "role121", children : [
          { label : "subUser2-1-1", id : "role1211", children : [] },
          { label : "subUser2-1-2", id : "role1212", children : [] }
        ],collapsed:true}
      ],collapsed:true}
    ], collapsed:true},

    { label : "Admin", id : "role2", children : [] },

    { label : "Guest", id : "role3", children : [] }
  ];
```

Answer (score 1):

use collapsed="true"

```
<div ui-tree="options">
            <ol ui-tree-nodes="" ng-model="data" id="tree-root">
                <li ng-repeat="item in data" ui-tree-node ng-include="'nodes_renderer.html'" data-collapsed="true"></li>
            </ol>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the data-collapsed attribute on a tree node:

```
<li ui-tree-node ng-repeat="item in notes" data-collapsed="{{ item.IsCollapsed }}">
```

The part that got me was that you'll want to apply an action (ng-class, ng-if, etc) of some kind to the child tree according to the collapse state of the current node:

```
<ol ui-tree-nodes="" ng-model="item.ChildList" ng-if="!collapsed">
```

Hope that helps!